# Why is Filter returning an empty array after filtering the values I need?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to carry out some flatmapping and filtering on an array of objects, however, I'm not sure why my final result - after filtering, is still displaying the same number of objects where in some of them, the `events` property has an empty array.

Object to handle (res) variable:

```
[
    {
        logs: [
                {
                    events: [
                                {
                                    "type": "unbond",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "delegate",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "someOther",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "withdraw_rewards",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type" : "someOtherOther",
                                    ...
                                },
                                ...
                            ]
                }

        timestamp: "someDate"
    },
        {
        logs: [
                {
                    events: [
                                {
                                    "type": "withdraw_commission",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "someOtherOtherOther",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "someOther",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "withdraw_rewards",
                                    ...
                                },
                                {
                                    "type" : "someOtherOther",
                                    ...
                                },
                                ...
                            ]
                }

        timestamp: "someDate"
    },
    ...
]
```

Result (after item 5, eveything has an empty array in the `event_logs` prop:

```
[
    {
        timestamp: "somedate1",
        event_logs: [
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
    },
        {
        timestamp: "somedate2",
        event_logs: [
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
    },
        {
        timestamp: "somedate3",
        event_logs: []              //empty
    },
    ...

]
```

Here is the code I used to carry out the flatmapping and filtering:

```
const evnts = res.data.tx_responses.map(({timestamp, logs}) => ({
    timestamp,
    event_logs: logs.flatMap(log => log.events)
                    .filter(events => events.type === "delegate" || events.type === "withdraw_rewards" || events.type === "withdraw_commission" || events.type === "unbond")
}));
return evnts;
```

How can I get rid of those objects with an empty `event_logs` prop?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ -> Add a [mcve] that reproduces the problem (example data is missing).

Comment: None of the elements in events fulfill the condition of the filter, that's why the empty arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a map of all but not filtering it in the resultant.
if you want to remove evens that does not have any event_log in them you can filter them as shown.

```
    const evnts = res.data.tx_responses.map(({timestamp, logs}) => ({
            timestamp,
            event_logs: logs.flatMap(log => log.events)
                            .filter(events => events.type === "delegate" || events.type === "withdraw_rewards" || events.type === "withdraw_commission" || events.type === "unbond")
        }));
//filter here
        evnts = evnts.filter(event => event.event_logs.length > 0 )
        return evnts;
```